# ErrorDocument 404 .htaccess not working with Rewrite Rule 301 for canonical

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I am using the following code in .htaccess file to sort out canonical redirects in Apache server. This works very well and redirects example.com, example.com/index.html and www.example.com/index.html ALL to www.example.com :-

```
#Redirect to www location
#Redirect example.com to www.example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

The above code works perfectly in .htaccess

I ALSO would like to have a ErrorDocument 404 rule to send visitors who arrive at non-existent pages to a specially designed page, namely: http://example.com/404/404.html

HOWEVER, when I add the following line to my .htaccess file, it does nothing. Ie navigating to a non-existent page (for example entering url www.example.com/asidhaskudhsadh just returns a standard 404 error page). The code I am trying to use is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404/404.html
```

(Ps. this is not an absolute url address issue as is often the case, because I have tried it with

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.google.com
```

and it still doesn't work. Whether I include the ErrorDocument line or not, the canonical redirects continue to work. The ErrorDocument line basically seems to have no effect at all.

Any ideas? My whole .htaccess file code is reproduced below. The strange line at the bottom was put in by an external mobile website development team to check whether visitors are on mobile devices and should go to the mobile version of the website (namely, http://www.example.com/m). The index.php file that it refers to is also included below.

**.htaccess file**

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404/404.html

#Redirect example.com to www.example.com
#Redirect to www location
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]


##### Speed Up Loading With Caching of Files #####
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# YEAR
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200"
</FilesMatch>
# WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
# 45 MIN
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2700"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

###### DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE!!! ######
DirectoryIndex index.php
###### DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE!!! ######
```

The desktop website loads using index.**html**

The index.**php** file code which is referenced in the last line of .htaccess file is as below:

```
<?php
ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' );
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

/* recomment in for mobile activation */
//echo @file_get_contents("index.html");

if(isset($_GET["m"]) && $_GET["m"] == "off"){
    $expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24;
    setcookie("mobile", "off", $expire);
    echo @file_get_contents("index.html");
} else if (isset($_COOKIE["mobile"]) && $_COOKIE["mobile"] == "off"){
    echo @file_get_contents("index.html");
} else if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true){ 
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/m/home.php");
} else {
    echo @file_get_contents("index.html");
}

?>
```